# Update multidimensional array but only take the last updated

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working with a multidimensional array whose dimensions are based on user input. I am reusing some logic methods from a DLL provided to me. However, I am facing a problem where the multidimensional array only takes the latest updated value, instead of updating for all values. Can you please help me identify the issue? Thank you very much.

Here is my code.

```
int size = fileDll.getArraySizeOp((int)Method.X); //size is 36
var getAllById = await _exampleRepository.GetAllById(id);
var getWPData = await _exampleWPRepository.GetById(id);
var duration = getWPData.Duration;
var convertOPDataToArray = getAllById.ToArray();
int dimension = convertOPDataToArray.Length;
float[] opValues = new float[size];
float[,] wpValues = new float[dimension, size];
Console.WriteLine($"Number of operations: {dimension}, size of each operation: {size}");
foreach (var item in convertOperationDataToArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n" +"=== Operation "+item.Oper_Id+" ===");
    opValues[0] = item.Frequency;
    Console.WriteLine($"Frequency: {opValues[0]}");
    opValues[1] = item.Frequency_Duration;
    Console.WriteLine($"Frequency_Duration: {opValues[1]}");
    opValues[2] = item.Vertical_Begin;
    Console.WriteLine($"Vertical_Begin: {opValues[2]}");

    ....

    opValues[34] = 0;
    opValues[35] = 0;

    fileDll.calculateOperation(opValues, duration);

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            wpValues[i, j] = opValues[j];
        }
    }

}

wpResult = fileDll.calculateWorkplace(wpValues, dimension, size, duration);
Console.WriteLine($"Workplace result : {wpResult}");
```

For example if I have 3 dimensions, the wpValues only take the third and then the result comes incorrect.

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which in turn will help you write better code.

Comment: it isn't clear from that code which value is not what you expect; however, I'm not seeing any "captures", which is the typical cause of things like "index not what I expected"; can you make it *really, really clear* what value is unexpected? ideally a minimal repro, i.e. something we can run and see what you're seeing, along with a "but I expected" explanation

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my previous message. I am facing a problem where I have three different arrays named "Operation". I assign each of them to the array named "opValues[]" and then use a method from a DLL to calculate the values. However, I am missing a capture value to store all three arrays. As a result, the "opValues[]" array only receives the third array, which is the last one. Could you please advise me on how to create a capture value to hold all three arrays? @MarcGravell

Comment: Ok well I will assume that you want wpValues to in your example case have three arrays with all their opVals. But in your doble for loop at the end you just keep overwriting everything. Is it really need for you to have that for dimension loop?

Comment: @GiaHuy ' I have three different arrays named "Operation" ' - arrays don't have names, and you aren't showing three for us to understand; '  I assign each of them to the array named "opValues[]"  ' - where? `opValues ` is assigned a *new* array in the code you post; '  Could you please advise me on how to create a capture value to hold all three arrays? ' - a variable can only hold one value at a time, so ... it is unclear what you mean here; what you are describing in words is not shown in the code you've posted, so I'm not sure how we can help here; can you make it *clear* where you're stuck

Comment: @MarcGravell well if I get this correctly then its a simple mistake. I think for each item/dimesnion they want to save all opValues from that item. So 3 dimensions == 3 items == a multiarray holding three arrays that represent their respective items opValues. The thing is that they have a double for loop at the end where they just override EVERYthing. In my assumption the wp array should hold all opValues of item one at wp[0], all opValues for item 2 at wp[1] and so on. But they throw all opValues in all wp positions meaning only the last one gets left

Comment: You might want to consider your naming, `float[,]` is called a 2 dimensional array, `float[,,]` 3 dimensional etc. So your `dimension` terminology could easily be confusing.

Comment: @SMSTJ Yes, you are right! I apologize for the unclear explanation. First, I created an empty array called opValues[] with a size of 36. In the foreach loop, I have three items. I assigned the first item to the opValues[] array and saved it to wpValues[0, j(0-35)], and did the same for wpValues[1, j(0-35)] and wpValues[2, j(0-35)]. However, my last two loops overrode everything. I hope this explanation is clearer for you.

Comment: @GiaHuy take a look at my Answer. If I understood you correctly that should solve it

Comment: @JonasH sorry for the confusion regarding the naming. To clarify, it is a 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whilst I think we should be given a bit more detail on what you want Im running on the assumtion that you want to get all opValues for each item/dimension and save that. In that case you simply need to get rid of your for dimension loop. Now I am somewhat confused as to the use of calculateOperation. Is this supposed to return something, or does it change something in the array?

```cs
    //your code
    int currentDimension = 0;//My addition
    foreach (var item in convertOperationDataToArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" +"=== Operation "+item.Oper_Id+" ===");
        opValues[0] = item.Frequency;
        Console.WriteLine($"Frequency: {opValues[0]}");
        opValues[1] = item.Frequency_Duration;
        Console.WriteLine($"Frequency_Duration: {opValues[1]}");
        opValues[2] = item.Vertical_Begin;
        Console.WriteLine($"Vertical_Begin: {opValues[2]}");
    
        ....
    
        opValues[34] = 0;
        opValues[35] = 0;
    
        fileDll.calculateOperation(opValues, duration);
    
        //changed your loop
        
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            wpValues[currentDimension, j] = opValues[j];
        }
        
        currentDimension++;
    }
    
    wpResult = fileDll.calculateWorkplace(wpValues, dimension, size, duration);
    Console.WriteLine($"Workplace result : {wpResult}");
```

So this should do it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solves the issue. The method calculateOperation is a void method used to calculate additional fields in the opValues[] array. To elaborate further, only 8 fields within the opValues[] array are inputted by the user, whereas the remaining fields (from 8 to 35) are generated by the calculateOperation method.